# Ubuntu 20.04 themes and icon are not expected

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, themes

I have just ungraded ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

After that my computer's look and feel has become so ugly.

I have also installed gnome tweek and extensions. Noting is working properly. Default appearance not working too. How can I fix it? How can I get the default icon and proper themes which is used in ubuntu 20.04?

See the screen shots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

Try these settings...

In `Tweaks`... choose a Yaru variant theme... light or dark, depending on your taste... and choose the Adwaita icon theme... choose a different background Desktop image, if you like...

[image]

In `Appearance` settings panel...

Choose a light/standard/dark theme, depending on your taste...

[image]

Comment: None of worked. Your screenshot have some options which I didn't have. Window color in in appearance was not selectable.
I had to uninstall tweek and extensions. Then I ran `sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-sound yaru-theme-gnome-shell yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-unity`
After that all the problem gone

Comment: @TusharMonirul Great news! Thanks for the update. My answer still applies, and Tweaks is still a good application to have.